# Unable to call `change` event for cloned `select` control

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have dynamically added new row by clone the last row, this row contains `select` picker control.

How can I create the `change` event for newly added control.

I have tried by adding below script, but it does not work:

```
console.log($('#${field_uid}-resourcetypepicker-new_' + u).attr('value'));  //prints  value correctly.
```

//below event is not called.

```
 $('#${field_uid}-resourcetypepicker-new_' + u).change(function() {   
        
        console.write('calling fine');
 });
```

Below is the rendered HTML stuff, copied from Firebug:

```
 <select id="customfield_11200-resourcetypepicker-new_3">
     <option value="aaa">aaa</option>
     <option value="ddd">ddd</option>
     <option value="ddd">ddd</option>
 </select>
```

Qhat can be the cause on this? Its IDs are also match in `change` and `select` both are `customfield_11200-resourcetypepicker-new_3` same.

Comment: Show the code where you dynamically generate the control.

Comment: _"create the change event...event is not called"_ - Are you trying to bind a handler for the change event, or _trigger_ a change event? Your wording is a little ambiguous.

Comment: thanks for your comments. it resolved the issue by follow below answer. but facing an issue inside change event.. please look at below answer's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use on delegated event

```
$(document).on('change','#${field_uid}-resourcetypepicker-new_' + u,function() { 
   console.write('calling fine');
 });
```

use closest static parent instead of document... for better performance

Comment: Thanks, it works. But inside this change event, assigning `select` list value to `hidden` field but in firebug it does not show me assigned value. Below is the related stuff: 
`$(document).on('change','#${field_uid}-resourcetypepicker-new_' + u,function() {AJS.$('#${field_uid}-resourcetype-new_' + u ).attr('value',AJS.$(this).attr('value'));
console.log('calling final:'+AJS.$('#${field_uid}-resourcetype-new_' + u ).val()); //this statement prints me correct updated value but in firebug not reflect.
 });` how we could resolve it ?`hidden` field is also cloned along with `select`field in a row.

Comment: use prop() instead of attr() if you are using latest version of jquery ..ie jquery1.6+

Comment: it is working through prop() and attr() also, actually, sometimes firebug unable to inspect correct value but it was updated while keep firebug off. Just to share, also,in cloned row, it contains button control and its click event javascript, for button click event, i needed to use as below `AJS.$(document).on('click', '#finaladd', function(event){if (event.handled !== true) {.....event.handled=true;}return false; });//so by this way, control existed in both div and its events attached two times though it works correctly.` Thank You friends.